# Query to get rows for specific user where revenue > revenue of earliest date for that user

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I have a table called user_revenue which looks like this[image]

So the query I need, if ran for the user 'AAA' should only return the last row.

```
SELECT *
FROM user_revenue 
WHERE user_Id = 'AAA'  /*Change according to user_id*/
AND revenues > (SELECT revenues FROM (
SELECT revenues, MIN(date) FROM user_revenue
WHERE user_id='AAA' ))/*Change according to user_id*/
```

I managed to write this which gets the job done, but ideally I'd like to only have to type the user_id one time in the query (whereas here it needs to be typed twice), is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your query doesn't really make sense.  You have a `MIN()` with another column but not aggregation.  What is the logic for getting the "last" row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias the table `user_revenue` like `u` in the main body of the query and use `u.user_Id` in the subquery wherever needed:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user_revenue u
WHERE u.user_Id = 'AAA'
AND u.revenues > (
  SELECT revenues FROM user_revenue
  WHERE user_Id = u.user_Id 
  AND date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM user_revenue WHERE user_Id = u.user_Id)
)
```

or:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user_revenue u
WHERE u.user_Id = 'AAA'
AND u.revenues > (
  SELECT revenues 
  FROM user_revenue
  WHERE user_Id = u.user_Id
  ORDER BY date
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent row for a user, you don't need any subqueries:

```
SELECT ur.*
FROM user_revenue ur
WHERE ur.user_Id = 'AAA'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```